# Node JS cannot find module error for file in another folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If i have schema.js in the same folder as index.js doing something like

`var schemas = require('./schema');`

works fine, but if i put the schema.js in another folder and write

`var schemas = require('./folder/schema');`

i get an error `Cannot find module` whats happening?

Edit1 : I got rid of the error by using ..folder/schema instead of single. and the server runs but it still doesn't work properly as I cant use the mongoosedb object returned through module.export from ../model/schema in the index.js file. It says myModel.find is not a function. Whats going on??

controllers/findallusers.js

```
var myModel = require('../models/schema');

var alluser;

myModel.find({}, function(err, foundData){   
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send();
  }
  else{
        alluser = foundData;
      }

    console.log(alluser); <-- this log is defined
});

    console.log(alluser); <-- this log is undefined

    module.exports = alluser; <-- cant export anything
```

Comment: Is the `folder` directory in the same directory as the index.js file?

Comment: i mean i have a router folder with index.js and a model folder which has schema.js

Comment: and im exporting the schema object using `module.export` in schema,js and trying to use it in index.js by `var schemas = require('./model/schema');`

Comment: It appears that `.find()` is asynchronous. Therefore IT IS IMPOSSIBLE to return it via module.exports. Instead, export a function that accept a callback or return a promise.

Comment: @slebetman I'm doing what pawan mentioned, exporting a function `list : funtion(req, res){ }` but getting syntax error at `list: function(req, res) {` whats going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolve path to schema.js correctly

Assuming your project structure like this

```
Project
 |
 +-- routers
 |  |  
 |  +-- index.js    
 +-- models
 |  |  
 |  +-- schema.js


//in index.js 
var schemas = require('../models/schema');
```

To solve second error i.e myModel.find not a function use, module.exports instead of using module.export

```
module.exports = myModel;
```

Resolution to your 3rd Problem

```
// controllers/findallusers.js --> (keep name simple  i.e userController.js)
var myModel = require('../models/schema');

module.exports =  {

    /**
     * Get All Users
     */
    list: function(req, res) {
       myModel.find({},function(err, users){
          if(err) {
              return res.status(500).json({message: 'Error getting Users.'});
          }
         return res.json(users);
      });
    },
   /**
    * Keep Adding more functions as you want
   */

   create: function(req,res){
       //functionality to create user
   },

   delete: function(req,res){
      // functionality to delete user
   },

   someDummyName: function(callback) {
       myModel.find({},function(err, users){
          if(err) {
            return callback(err)
          }
         return callback(null,users);
      });
    }       

}
```

//
Solution to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504219/how-to-use-use-callbacks-or-promises-to-return-a-object-from-an-asynchronous-fun

```
//index.js call this new method i.e someDummyName as  
router.get('/allusers', function(req, res){       

    userController.someDummyName(function(err,result){
      if(err) {
        //return err
      }
      //process result as per your need
    });

});
```

Comment: Is this real life? using two dots before /model/schema just solved the issue -_-

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work properly.. I cant use the mongoosedb object returned through `module.export` from `../model/schema` in the `index.js` file. It says `myModel.find` is not a function.  Whats going on??

Comment: I have added the code, also using the model/schema code directly in the index.js works just fine

Comment: check my edited answer, and if its solved all your issues accept the answer.

Comment: Please read my last edit, i used the .exports a while ago (that was silly of me) and im stuck in a new problem. can you tell me why alluser is getting undefined right after the call back function?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/39481543/4066767, I have explained it over there

Comment: So can i use the `module.exports` inside the async function? doing that also returning null value { } in the log. How can use that db result?

Comment: check resolution to your 3rd problem I'v edited the answer again..!

Comment: Im getting error over here : `list: function(req, res){` `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (` whats wrong?

Comment: check edited answer now, module.exports need to be object.

Comment: Okay, i used the data by going `  console.log(allUser.list());` and its working. for now :)

Comment: Turn out i was using console.log(users) in list : function, please tell me how to send the objects as json because its saying `Cannot read property 'json' of undefined` when i use `return res.json(users);`

Comment: you need to call list() by passing req,res i.e allUser.list(req,res)

Comment: var userController = require('../controllers/findallusers');  
app.get('/allusers', function (req, res) {
   userController.list(req,res)
})

Comment: okay i get what is happening, but doesn't this mean that we are using the controller.js file for no reason?

Comment: then pass only callback function to the list and change your list function accordingly. it would be better if you move this to a new question so that scope of this question will remain unchanged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504219/how-to-return-json-objects-from-a-async-function I have moved this to another question as you suggested.

Comment: Also what do you mean by passing only the callback function, can you quickly explain it here ?

Comment: sure. I'm adding a new method to the same answer which will accept callback

Comment: check now and to understand callback check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216699/what-is-the-callback-in-loopback-datasource-automigrate/37222240#37222240 .

Comment: I think i have alot to learn about the asynchronicity of javascript but right now im running late for my class lol thanks again for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting a variable myModel from schema.js and importing just schema in index.js

So, try to reference the .find function using `myModel.myModel.find()` My guess is that the myModel variable is behind your existing myModel variable in index.js

Comment: created a package.json file in /models/ folder with what you mentioned. still getting error `Cannot find module './models/schema'`

Comment: Using `..models/schema` solved the server issue of module not found error, but now i cant use the database model object which is exported from schema.js in the index.js. whats going on... can you help?

Comment: Theres my attempt, havnt used mongoose before but in my initial research of it, i think that my be it